# PHP remove part of a url in an array element

Tags: php, arrays, url, replace

I have a `.csv` file which I have converted into an array `$outputData`. The 6th `$data[6]` element of each array contains an image file path, e.g.

```
http://images.pleaserusa.com/pic/unique.image.jpg
```

I need to remove the the filepath `http://images.pleaserusa.com/pic/` of each image and leave just the image name itself, e.g.

```
unique.image.jpg
```

I have looked on here and Google and tried to use `preg_match()` and `str*` functions, but I'm not really getting anywhere with it.

Rizer123 I have placed the "basename" function but can't get it to replace inside the element . i can only get it to echo/print outside the array / i have placed the code below and an excerpt array out put below .

```
domina-456-b.jpgArray
(
    [0] => DOM456/B
    [1] => 6" Lace-Up Pump W/ D-Ring&Ribbon Lace
    [2] => Devious
    [3] => Single Soles
    [4] => DOMINA-456
    [5] => Blk Pat
    [6] => http://images.pleaserusa.com/pic/domina-456-b.jpg
    [7] => 5-15
)
domina-460-b.jpgArray
(
    [0] => DOM460/B
    [1] => 6" Oxford Lace Up Pump
    [2] => Devious
    [3] => Single Soles
    [4] => DOMINA-460
    [5] => Blk Pat
    [6] => http://images.pleaserusa.com/pic/domina-460-b.jpg
    [7] => 5-16
)

<?php 

$input = 'Parser/Inv_item.csv';
$output = 'hd_inv_items.csv';

if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) {
    $oh = fopen($output, 'w');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) {
    // this is where you build your new row
    $outputData = array($data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3],   $data[5],$data[6], $data[9], $data[8]);

$path = $data[9];
$name = basename($path); // $name == '1.jpg'

print_r($name);

print_r($outputData);

//fputcsv($oh, $outputData);        

}   
fclose($ih);
fclose($oh);
}

?>
```

As you can see the image file path is still in the array and the basename result is printing outside of the array . How do i fix this issue

Regards Biwwabong

Comment: Please add your attempt into your question! Also please include the structure of your array!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for explosions or string manipulations for this, a simple [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) should suffice:

```
$path = 'http://images.pleaserusa.com/pic/unique.image.jpg';
echo basename($path);
```

output:

```
unique.image.jpg
```

---

[`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) would work as well:

```
echo pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

Comment: With answering questions where no effort is shown you are supporting such behaviour!

Comment: @Rizier123 i apologize, sometimes i do get tempted, i'm a sucker for this, especially with the field of answers, there's a much simpler approach. lol

Comment: *especially with the field of answers, there's a much simpler approach* <- I know what you mean :) Then you're really on a fence. (I think I would have also put an answer with `basename()` in, if you didn't already posted it and the other answers were much too complicated)

Answer (score 1):

I always do this with `explode()`

```
$url = "http://images.pleaserusa.com/pic/unique.image.jpg";
$parts = explode("/",$url);
$pic = $parts[count($parts)-1];
```

You are welcome ;-)